# Apache CXF not releasing clients

Tags: java, apache, web-services, cxf, jax-ws

I've discovered my application is heavily leaking memory.  After taking heap dumps it appears Apache CXF (2.7.7) seems to be referencing lots of JaxWsServiceConfiguration (14000 in a day).

I'm not sure if I am using it correctly, whether I need to somehow release the client or there is a bug in CXF.  Hopefully somebody can point me in the right direction here.

I am using a `JaxWsProxyFactoryBean` injected into my service methods.  The following line is called to create the client proxy (called for **every** request to the web service):

```
jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create();
```

Eventually the service method finishes but it looks like the factory holds reference to the client proxy and therefore never GCs it.

I thought I could create a single static client and always use this but am a little nervous of this since it is not thread-safe in all circumstances: http://cxf.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-AreJAX-WSclientproxiesthreadsafe?

Should I be doing this differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use static proxies all the time when I build gateways to consume a web service on behalf of hundreds of concurrent clients. It should be no problem whatsoever as long as the interceptor chain is not modified for a given request, for example modification to the conduit or use of sessions.

Comment: Thanks, I have ended up implementing this as well

Comment: @mnik Could you please give reference to the implementation. How did you solve this. I am facing similar problem

Comment: @dinesh I only run create() once and store that as a class variable