# Memory leaks in Java and spring using JaxWsProxyFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, memory-leaks, cxf

I have an application in Java that uses CXF to make calls to a web service. The code for the initiator looks like

```
import org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.tempuri.IAPIService;

import javax.inject.Inject;

/**
 * Created by flavius on 23/09/14.
 */
@Component()
public class VsJaxWsProxyFactory {

  @Inject
  private Environment env;

  private JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factoryBean = null;

  public Object create() {
    if (factoryBean == null) {

      factoryBean = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
      factoryBean.setServiceClass(IAPIService.class);
      factoryBean.setAddress(env.getProperty("api.wsdl"));
    }
    return factoryBean.create();
  }
}
```

The application runs fine, but after a while the box starts to consume too much memory and the application starts running slow. When we tried to do a memory analysis we found the following
[image: Memory Analysis]

It seems that the CXF is somehow creating a new Service configuration object on each call, and is not being released. I can't find much information on org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceConfiguration class and not sure if this is a configuration issue or some internal bug in some library.

Answer (score 2):

Already answered here:
[Apache CXF not releasing clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26403674/apache-cxf-not-releasing-clients)

Basically .create() method on the same JaxWsProxyFactoryBean instance should be called only **once**, otherwise you get a memory leak:

```
return factoryBean.create();
```

factoryBean.create() returns the cxf JAX-WS client proxy, which you can reuse for **repeated** calls. Created client is also thread safe if you don't use any special features mentioned here http://cxf.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-AreJAX-WSclientproxiesthreadsafe?